# ABC - A Blokus Commitment

Tags: board-games, polyomino

Welcome to [Blokus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blokus), a board game where you can place pieces of 1 to 5 blocks on a square board.
Each player has at his disposal every piece from monomino to [pentomino](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentomino).

A player's inventory is composed of 21 pieces, accumulating 89 squares in total :

[image: player's inventory in Blokus]

All of these polyminoes are *free*, this means that you can rotate or flip them as you wish before placing them on the board.

**The rules**

Now what do we have to do in this puzzle ?
Let's pick 2 natural numbers $k$ and $n$, and we'll try to place our pieces on a ($n*n$) square board to have exactly $k$ squares in **each row** and **each column**.

That gives us the following constraints :

- $0 < n$
- $0 < k \le n$
- $k*n \le 89$ (total number of placeable blocks)

Another rule is that each placed polymino **musn't touch by the edge** another polymino of the same color. It can however touch its **corners**, or the edges of an opponent's polymino.

For example, here are some possible cases of ($k,n$) done with 1 player :

```
(1,1) (2,2) (2,3) (2,4)  (2,5)   (3,5)
+-    +--   +---  +----  +-----  +-----
|P    |BB   |P W  |VV    |BB     |LLL
      |BB   | WW  |V  W  |BB     |L  VV
            |WW   |  WW  |   WW  | SS V
                  | WW   |  WW   |SS T 
                         |  W P  |  TTT
```

Some example done with 2 players :

```
(3,3) (3,4) (4,4)
+---  +---- +----
|vvv  |LLL  |VVVp
|BBv  |vv L |VzzQ
|BBv  |v tL |VzQQ
      | ttt |zzQQ
```

And some impossible cases for 1 player :

- ($n,n$) for $n>2$ : we would need a single piece of $n^2$ blocks (which is impossible), since any other piece that is composed of less blocks will create un-fillable blanks around its edges when placed.
- ($1,n$) for $n>1$ : you would need $n$ monominoes, which a single player has not in its inventory (and no, don't tear the blocks apart from others pieces, that's just brutal)

also :

- $k=4$, the 5-line piece can't be placed, total of placeable blocks for each player is $84$.
- $k=3$, the 4-line tetromino, the long L pentomino and the Y pentomino can't be placed either, this reduces the total placeable blocks for each player to $70$
- $k=2$, Only 6 pieces can be placed, and W is the only pentomino. total of placeable blocks for each player is $19$.

**Scoring :**

After completing a ($k,n$) board, the score will be evaluated as follows :

$$P = p1^2 + p2^2 + p3^2 + p4^2$$
$$Score = P/U * M$$

- $pX$ is the number of placed block from the inventory of player $X$
- $U$ is the number of players involved in completing the board (placed blocks > 0)

  - For the record, $U>0$, because $k>0$
  - Also, $U\le 4$
- $M$ is a bonus multiplier

  - $M=1$ if $U=1$, or at least two pieces of different colors share an edge.
  - $M=1.5$ if $U>1$ and no pair of pieces of any color share an edge.

**The challenges :**

- Maximize $(k,n) = (5, 10)$
- Maximize $(k,n) = (3, 20)$

I have found some scores on these that I believe can be optimized. But I'm actively trying to find out if the score on these 2 particular problems can or can not be completed using 1 player's inventory (which wields the best score)

And if you have found any perfect ($k,n$) boards (completed with only 1 player's set), don't hesitate to put them here.

Comment: You could have at least put some link for your [inspiration](https://www.amazon.fr/Jeux-BJV44-Jeu-Soci%C3%A9t%C3%A9-Blokus/dp/B00FBWBM3G)

Comment: Pretty sure in the original game, your next piece has to be corner to corner with at least one of your existing pieces, I assume from your examples that you are allowing piece placement that violates this.

Comment: @Arth Indeed. Here, every pair of same coloured piece *can* be connected to the corners, but it isn't an obligation, and if it was, it would have made the (3,20) board impossible, right away.

Comment: See my answer for a $(k,n) = (3,20)$ with one player's pieces (not sure if adding solutions to my original post through edits triggers a new notification, so I'm throwing in this comment to make sure it doesn't get missed).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Perfect board for $(k,n) = (3,20)$:

I did my diagram in Excel, since that was easier to disguise as real work at the office. I'll continue adding more if/when I find them.

> [image]
>  Plaintext:
>
> ```
>     AA.................B
>     AA.................B
>     A....C.............B
>     ....CC....D.........
>     .....CC...D.........
>     .........DDD........
>     ..............E.FF..
>     .............EE.F...
>     .............E.FF...
>     ..G....HH...........
>     .GGG................
>     ..G...I..J..........
>     ........JJ.....K....
>     .............KKK....
>     ......LLL...........
>     ...MM..L............
>     ...MM.......N.......
>     ............N....OO.
>     ...........NN.....O.
>     ...........N.....OO.
> ```
>
> $Score = 60^2 = 3,600$

### $(k,n) = (4,9)$

> [image: Perfect (4,9)]
>  Plaintext:
>
> ```
>     ..AA..BB.
>     .AA..C.B.
>     ...CCC.B.
>     .DD.C.E..
>     DD....E.F
>     D....EE.F
>     ..G..E.FF
>     H..II...F
>     HH.II....
> ```

### $(k,n) = (4,10)$

> [image: 4,10]
>  Plaintext:
>
> ```
>     AAA......B
>     AA..C....B
>     ..CCC..D..
>     ....C.DDD.
>     EEEE......
>     E...FF.G..
>     .....FF.HH
>     ...I.F..HH
>     .III..J...
>     .....JJJJ.
> ```

### $(k,n) = (4,11)$

> [image]
> Plaintext:
>
> ```
>     AA...BB....
>     AA...BB....
>     A......C.DD
>     ...E...CC.D
>     ..EEE.....D
>     ..E...F.GG.
>     .....FF..GG
>     ....FF.HH..
>     IIII.......
>     ....J..KKK.
>     .JJJJ......
> ```

Comment: Good job on the (3, 20)!

Comment: Well, I can stop trying now... I hope both of you (Steve and @WesleySitu) had a fun time doing this. the (5,10) and (3, 20) boards really left me hopeless at some point. :)

Comment: We could theoretically go up to $(3,23)$, so if you'd like to keep looking at that, feel free :P

Answer (score 5):

(this community wiki answer is used to show the current progress)

### Solutions

$(5,10)$ Perfect

> [image: huzzah!]

$(5,10)$ incomplete

> [image: 2 blocks shy of the ultimate win !]
>
> $P = 48^2 + 2^2 = 2308$
>
> $Score = (2308/2)*1.5 = 1731$

($3,20$) incomplete

> [image: (3,20) board, 2 players]
>
> $P = 56^2 + 4^2 = 3152$
>
> $Score = 3152/2*1.5 = 2364$

### Board Tileset

[image: template for blokus grid]

### Operating on a board

How to manipulate squares on a board without messing up the numbers of blocks in the rows & columns ?
(These operations below aren't practicable on a real board)

***Shift*** all the squares in the same direction, and loop those which exit the board.

***Swap*** 2 squares ($A$ and $B$) :
if the squares on the location $(X_A, Y_B)$ and $(X_B, Y_A)$ are **empty**,
then you can remove $A$ and $B$ and place the squares on these new locations.

Comment: Nice diagrams & tileset. But how did you create the diagrams?

Comment: @RosieF I used Graphics gale, using custom grid snapping and copy pasting.

Comment: Thanks, @Anton. I had a quick look at the web site. It looks as if using that software to produce such images would be extremely complicated and time-consuming.

Comment: @RosieF I guess using the tileset (or just rects) and simple PowerPoint is a quick and easy alternative...

Comment: Never mind -- I found that Ghostgum's GSview can save in PNG format. (Full page, but Paint can crop the image). And I already know enough PostScript to program what I need. Thank you for your suggestions anyway.

Answer (score 5):

### Perfect boards

### $k = 2$ : possible for $n\in 2..9$

Combined with the (2, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4) and (2, 5) in the first post, this is complete, as $n \geq 10$ requires $k \cdot n \geq 20$ blocks, but if $k = 2$ only 19 blocks can be placed (as stated in the question).

(2,6)

> [image: 2 6 perfect board]
>  plain text version:
>
> ```
> .AA...
> AA....
> A..B..
> ..BB..
> ....CC
> ....CC
> ```

(2,7)

> [image: 2 7 perfect board]
>  in plain text:
>
> ```
> A...B..
> ...BB..
> ..BB...
> .....CC
> .....CC
> .DD....
> DD.....
> ```

(2,8)

> [image: 2 8 perfect board]
>  in plain text:
>
> ```
> AA......
> AA......
> ..BB....
> ..B....C
> ......CC
> .....CC.
> ...DD...
> ....DD..
> ```

(2,9)

> [image: 2 9 perfect board]
>  in plain text:
>
> ```
> .AA......
> .....BB..
> .....BB..
> CC.......
> C......D.
> .......DD
> ....E...D
> ...EE....
> ..EE.....
> ```

### $k = 3$, so far, solutions have been found when $n = 5..9$

(3,6)

> [image: 3 6 perfect board]
>  in plain text:
>
> ```
> AAA...
> A..BB.
> A...BB
> .CCC..
> .C.C.E
> ..D.EE
> ```
>
> And for the style : diagonals also have a 3 out of 6 completion.

(3,7)

> [image: 3 7 perfect board]
>  in plain text:
>
> ```
> A.BB...
> ....CCC
> DD...C.
> DD..E..
> ....EEE
> ..FF..E
> .FFF...
> ```

(3,8)

> [image: perfect 3 8]
>  in plain text:
>
> ```
> ..AA..C.
> ..AA.D..
> BB...D..
> B....D.E
> ....F.EE
> ....F.EE
> .G.FF...
> GGG.....
> ```

(3,9)

> [image: perfect 3 9]
>  in plain text:
>
> ```
> AAA......
> A.A.B....
> ...BB.D..
> ..BB..D..
> .....DDD.
> GG......E
> .G.....EE
> .....F.EE
> ...FFF...
> ```

### $k=4$

(4,4), (4,5), (4,6) are impossible, because there is not enough holes to separate the pieces.

(4,7)

> [image: perfect 4 7]
>  in plain text:
>
> ```
> AA.B.D.
> A.C..DD
> A.CCC..
> A..C.EE
> .GG.F.E
> .GG.F.E
> .G.FFF.
> ```

(4,8)

> [image: perfect 4 8]
>  in plain text:
>
> ```
> .AA..BB.
> AA....BB
> .A..CC.B
> D..E.CC.
> D.EEE...
> DD.E.F..
> ..G.G.HH
> ..GGG..H
> ```